# Laravel 4.2 scheduled:run commands not firing correctly

Tags: php, cron, laravel-4.2

I'm using [Dispatcher](https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher#tutorial) with Laravel 4.2 for scheduling & running cron jobs.

I've added my command and it's showing in `php artisan` correctly. If I run it from the terminal, it runs as expected.

As per instructions, I've added to crontab:

`* * * * * php /home/tti/public_html/artisan scheduled:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

If I run `scheduled:summary`, I can see my list as follows:

```
+----------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+------+--------------+-------+-------------+--------+
| Environment(s) | Name               | Args/Opts | Minute | Hour | Day of Month | Month | Day of Week | Run as |
+----------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+------+--------------+-------+-------------+--------+
| *              | cron:test          |           | *      | *    | *            | *     | *           |        |
+----------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+------+--------------+-------+-------------+--------+
```

And here's the code for the command:

```
<?php

use Indatus\Dispatcher\Scheduling\ScheduledCommand;
use Indatus\Dispatcher\Scheduling\Schedulable;
use Indatus\Dispatcher\Drivers\Cron\Scheduler;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class DatabaseBackup extends ScheduledCommand {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'wtf:test';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'This is a test.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * When a command should run
     *
     * @param Scheduler $scheduler
     * @return \Indatus\Dispatcher\Scheduling\Schedulable
     */
    public function schedule(Schedulable $scheduler)
    {
        // return $scheduler;

        return $scheduler
            ->daily()
            ->hours(3)
            ->minutes(20);

    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {

        Log::info('Cron test successful');
    }


}
```

Again, everything runs correctly from the terminal command.

When I wait for the cron to fire, I get the following error in my log:

```
local.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "wtf" namespace.' in /home/tti/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:514
Stack trace:
#0 /home/tti/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(548): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('wtf')
#1 /home/tti/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(188): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('wtf:databasebac...')
#2 /home/tti/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/tti/public_html/artisan(58): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#4 {main} [] []
[2016-08-13 15:35:01] local.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "wtf" namespace.' in /home/tti/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:514
Stack trace:
#0 /home/tti/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(548): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('cron')
#1 /home/tti/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(188): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('wtf:databasebac...')
#2 /home/tti/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/tti/public_html/artisan(58): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#4 {main} [] []
```

Why won't this run correctly?

Comment: Can you please share your whole file code in your question instead of only the fire method?  Also please let me know the PHP version you are using?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? If yes, then please share. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @MKJ - PHP 5.6.10; code updated.

Comment: @Jazzbot no solution yet. :(

Comment: Have you fixed the issue, because I was able to get it working. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Is related to namespace. If you change `protected $name = 'wtf:test';` to simply `protected $name = 'test';` or similar it will run